# Is it possible to analytically solve this question

Tags: complex-analysis, tetration

I came across this question which I successfully solved computationally, but I was wondering if there is an analytical way of doing it.

Find  Real and Imaginary parts of: $$ i^{i^{i^{i^{.^{.^ {2019}}}}}}$$

From Anas's comment it can be written as:

$${}^{2019} i$$

It also could be written as:

$i^{(i)^i} $ and so on till there are 2019  $i's$.

PS: I couldn't continue in this fashion further to show till 2019.

Comment: First of all note that $\mathrm i^{2019}=-\mathrm i$, then the question depends on how many $\mathrm i$'s you have.

Comment: Please be careful in reading this question. The powers do not come down to get multiplied.

Comment: I understand that. But still it depends on how many powers you have. Of course $i^{i^{-i}}$ is not the same as $i^{i^{i^{-i}}}$ and so on.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it depends. But what you have done is not the answer to my question since that gives answer to the 1st case.

Comment: Then how many $i$’s are there? $2019$?

Comment: Oh now I understand what you are saying. But 2019 refers to the number of i's, that is not the power of the last raised i. I hope you can see the dots that lead to the number 2019

Comment: The notation here is confusing

Comment: Please correct the notation. Let's take not 2019 times but only 3 times. Would that mean
$$
i^{(i^i)} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \left(i^i \right)^i
$$? Those are different things ...

Comment: I have added "tetration" to the keywords. Don't you think it is a very artificial question ?...

Comment: @Matti P. The former thing

Comment: @Jean Marie I dont know what you mean by an artifical question. But let me make it clear, its not that I cooked it up in my head someday. This was part of an assignment given for screeing during research internship in an institute.

Comment: And please do not down vote without giving reasons. I think this is perfectly valid way to ask this question.

Comment: 1) I am not the downvoter... 2) If people think in this institute that this exercise separates good candidates from bad ones, it is their right, but first of all they should include parentheses as remarked by Matti P...

Comment: You can use ${}^{2019} i$ to represent tetration.

Comment: @ Jean Marie I agree. As a matter of fact I was so confused between the two things that I gave two solution in that assignment but since I thought that was probably due to my lack of terminological limitation I didn't think it would create confusion here as well. I will edit the question as per Matti P's suggestion

Comment: Even after deciding you are intepreting the power tower top down, you still have another ambiguity to deal with. The top is $i^i$. Now $i = e^{i\pi(1/2 + 2k)}$ for any integer $k$. So $i^i = e^{-\pi(1/2 + 2k)}$. It is multi-valued. You can choose $k=0$, but then you run into the same problem next time. Eventually $\left(\frac \pi 2\right)^n > 2\pi$. At that point do you subtract $2\pi$ to stay on the same branch, or ignore it to get a nice answer? It is possible the institute is looking at whether candidates spot all the ambiguities, and how they handle them.

Comment: Yes it could be possible they wanted that. So the way I did it was by calculating the real and imaginary parts for two or three cases. It turned out that they followed a recursive relation so I put those relations in a loop and got the numerical answer. I took k=0 and I am interested in this case  but more general answers are welcome too. Also, answers which ignore the 2\pi subtraction are welcome too since I don't even know how to look for an analytical solution and hence any attempt (even with assumptions that simplify it) would be interesting to me.

Comment: If a (complex) base $z$ in the sequence $z, z^z, z^{(z^z)},...$ is in the "Shell-Thron-region" then you -at least- know the sequence converges, while it diverges if $z$ is outside of this region. You can see this region in the wikipedia-article on "tetration". After this, seeing that your base $i$ is ***in*** that region, you have at least an argument that you can numerically approximate (towards the fixpoint). However - having just some crude number $2019$ of iterations it cannot be expected that there is a "closed form" for this intermediate value on the(infinite long)road to the fixpoint...

Comment: Does this mean then that it is impossible to solve this analytically and the only way to proceed is through a numerical computation?

Comment: yes, that is what I think. Compare this for instance with the closed form for $\zeta(2)$ . It was one of L. Euler's great achievements to find a closed form for the underlying series. But that result was for the full series, as limit for inifinitely many terms. I think it is *intuitive* that the partial sum of some random index like $2019$ or $2018$ or $2020$ or $20192817161514$ or so should not have any closed form description...